# Encode base64 string in Node with substitute characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, encode

I am using .toString('base64') to encode a token which is later passed into the url. I need to substitute '/', '+', '=', and ',' with other characters. How do I do this?

Comment: base 64 doesn't include `,` ... use String#replace function to replace strings

Answer (score -1):

I discovered this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/urlsafe-base64 which does this automatically. It worked great!